# Slow performance when querying/sorting the top 1000 documents in a 17 million document Lucene.NET index

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I want to find the top 1000 documents in a Lucene.NET index that match a type and tag sorted by view count. My index contains 17 million documents. I am searching for type 'entity' and tag 'business'. Almost every document in the index right now has a type of 'entity' and a tag of 'business'. Both are string fields that are indexed but not analyzed and have no term vector. Right now it takes about 15-20 seconds to get results from this query.

Here is my code:

```
string subType = "entity";
string tag = "business";
BooleanQuery filterQuery = new BooleanQuery();
filterQuery.Add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("SubType", subType)), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
filterQuery.Add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("Tag", tag)), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("Views", global::Lucene.Net.Search.SortField.INT, true));
Filter queryFilter = new QueryWrapperFilter(filterQuery);
TopDocs docs = searcher.Search(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), queryFilter, 1000, sort);
```

Any suggestions on improving the performance are greatly appreciated. I have spent about 8 hours tweaking and messing with stuff. Right now I am caching the results for 15 minutes so that future searches can just return the cached results, but that initial search is just painfully slow.

It seems like the sets for the "entity" and "business" terms should compress to a few bytes assuming Lucene does any kind of run-length encoding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to use SQL to do the sorting when the frequency of the category is at a certain threshold (10% or more) and to use Lucene for any category that is in fewer than 10% of the documents. This has greatly improved performance as SQL is able to sort well when there is a high frequency (probably because it can walk both the Views index and the Category index to get the first 5000 quickly). SQL is slow when only a smaller percentage of the items match the category probably because it has to walk almost the entire Views index. Lucene is fast because it can filter super fast on just the items with a category and then sort those by views.

Answer (score 6):

Reality check: according to your specifications you are ordering 16830000 (16,83 million) documents to pull the top 1000.

This means they have to be loaded enough for sorting.

Yes. This will be slow.

CUT DOWN THE NUMBERS. Anything returning more than 10.000 items is doubtfull to be worth sorting.

Comment: I would hope Lucene would somehow use the Views field to cut down the result set rather than pulling every document in memory and then sorting. Seems a shame to sort all 17 million when the first few thousand docs in the views set could be used...

Comment: It still has to sort every document in the result set.  What if the 17 millionth document belongs first in the result set?

Comment: Exactly. THe problem is that your filters dont filter (99% hit rate makes it useless) so you end up with a HUGH document sort. And it needs to check every document because, as gualie7960 said, the last document it looks at could be the one belonging to the top.

Comment: You probably want to filter based on documents that were viewed at least X number of times.  That should help a lot.  Yes you might not get 1000 results, but at least the result will come much quicker.

Comment: Good point on the filter with views greater than X, I think I will try that out, as 95% have 0 views right now

Comment: So wouldn't a better approach be to check the term frequency for the SubType and Tag fields, and if it is a high percentage of documents, just start enumerating the view count in descending order and just pull in documents based on that?